# Computation - can you compute the gradient, Laplacian, divergence and curl of any function?

Tags: differentiation, vector-fields, mathematics, calculus

In my physics class, we are currently studying gradient, Laplacian, divergence, and curl, and we have a problem that states to compute all four of these (I.e., (1) gradient, (2) Laplacian, (3) divergence, and (4) curl) “as appropriate” for the given expressions.

Now I noticed that some of the expressions are vectors and some are not. I’ve been reading about divergence and curl and know somewhat how they apply to vectors, vector fields. But do they apply to functions as well?

Likewise, how can you take the partial derivative of a vector?

Of note, I understand that the gradient and curl can be zero but here I am talking not about one of these operations being zero but rather about possibly not being able to do it at all.

Comment: This is a mathematics question not a physics question, even if it is from a physics class you'd likely get a better answer on mathematics stackexchange

Comment: Thanks so much - I did that just now.

Answer (score 0):

> But do they apply to functions as well?

No!

[Divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence) is a vector operator that operates on a vector field, producing a scalar field giving the quantity of the vector field's source at each point. The divergence represents the volume density of the outward flux of a vector field from an infinitesimal volume around a given point.

The [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) is a vector operator that describes the infinitesimal circulation of a vector field in three-dimensional Euclidean space. The curl at a point in the field is represented by a vector whose length and direction denote the magnitude and axis of the maximum circulation.

---

> how can you take the partial derivative of a vector?

I would rather say vector field (or space-dependent vector (maybe time too)). For example :

$$\mathbf{F}=x\hat i +y\hat j+z \hat k$$

$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{F}}{\partial x}=\hat i$$

But there is no use in it.

> about possibly not being able to do it at all.

If the vector field and its derivative are well defined at a point then you can compute a well-defined value divergence and curl at that point. But It's not always the case for example
$$\mathbf{V}=\frac{1}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

has a singularity at origin thus you can not find the divergence just by differentiating.

Comment: Thank you so much for your long and detailed response! If you don’t mind, would it be possible to elaborate on what you mean by the vector space? What I have are not functions but expressions (such as x^2 + ysin(z)) - does that mean that I can draw a vector field, even though it isn’t in the form of a vector?

Comment: @Yelena $f(x, y, z) = x^2 + y\sin z$ would be a scalar field, not a vector field. For example, a vector field could be $f(x, y, z) = \langle x\sin y, z^2, 7\rangle$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space

Comment: I didn't use the word vector space though. You can't draw a vector field for the scalar function. But what you can do, if interested, take the gradient of the function and plot the field that will give you an idea How the function changes in space.